# Is there a way to combine a part of a command with text bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, file-copying

i want to have a user input a command to check if one directory has the same files as another one. (it's not complete but here's the area that i'm having trouble with)

```
echo "enter a command"
read command           #example: cp ../example/b*
mkdir new_directory
new_command = $command + "target/path/new/directory"     #this is where i'm having trouble
$new_command
```

not sure how to combine a command with some text to complete the cp command? I dont think "+" works here and i also tried cat.

Comment: @DigvijayS 
I have tried it out but when I echo the variable to make sure its the right command...nothing shows up
(This is what I tried based on that: s=${command} ' /target/path/new/directory' )

Comment: Always use `"` for variable expansion. Try `s="${command} /target/path/new/directory"`

Comment: @DigvijayS it works!! thanks for helping me out :D